# Air-datepicker ruins css and stays visible after adding dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to add air-datepicker dynamically but it ruins layout, stays visible and doesn't react on date select. Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_project_schedule").click(function() {
    var selected_project = "dddd";

    var block = '<div><div style="display: inline-block">Project: ' + selected_project + '&nbsp' + '</div><div class="date_from" style="display: inline-block"><b>From:&nbsp</b><input type="text" class="datepicker-here datepick" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" ></input></div><div class="date_to" style="display: inline-block"><b>To:&nbsp</b><input  type="text" class="datepicker-here datepick" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" ></input></div></div>';

    $("#project_container").append(block);
    $('.date_from').last().datepicker({
      inline: false,
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>



<div class="row">
  <button id="add_project_schedule">Add Project Schedule</button>
  <button id="save_schedules">Save changes</button>
  <div class="project_assign" id="project_container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have  evident syntax error at: `$('.date_to)` Also please create [mre] using <> button in editor to create a snippet. Images are no help to us.

Comment: this error doesn't relate to question actually

Comment: Sure it does, your whole javascript from that point is not working and is invalid. And even after that I asked for [mre]

Comment: added with link

Comment: I seen, I dont know the anwser, try to add bounty to bring attention to question.